# How to get the state updated of input field of google map api in React app

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, input, google-maps-api-3, react-state-management

According to the official docs of [google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox),
I was trying to implement the autocomplete search `input` in my `React` app as per the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class App extends Component {
    state = {
        location: ''
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ location: e.target.value });
    };
    render() {
        function initAutocomplete() {
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        }
        initAutocomplete();
        return (
            <input
                defaultValue={this.state.location}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                id="pac-input"
                className="controls"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search your College"
            />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and I managed to get it to work properly. But, the only problem that I'm seeing that whenever I select/click the autocomplete option, the value of the input bar gets updated with the selected address but not in the state.
You can check out this [short video demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mqNoXos07MuA0a8MSItxPUEpqvLOz-Eo) and please suggest me what changes should I do to get the state management working correctly?

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: @evan here you go: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-paper-ke3d4?file=/src/App.js)
make sure to lookup in the react dev tools for `this.state.location`

Comment: Thanks, I can see the problem. Let me give you a full answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're listening to the input's `onChange` event only, not the Autocomplete's `places_changed` event, so the input's `onChange` function doesn't run when you select a place from the autocomplete list of place suggestions. Try amending your code as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    location: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const app = this;
    function initAutocomplete() {
      var input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
      var searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      searchBox.addListener("places_changed", function() {
        app.setState({ location: document.getElementById("pac-input").value });
      });
    }
    initAutocomplete();
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ location: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        defaultValue={this.state.location}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        id="pac-input"
        className="controls"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search your College"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it is working but its not giving me the full address for exaple if i type and select MIT then instead of showing me `M.I.T, Massachusetts Avenue, Cambridge, MA, USA` in the state, the value of this.state shows like this `{
  "location": "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA"
}` and there was also one case when i typed `DY Patil` to get my collegeName `D Y Patil School Of Engineering Lohegaon, Lohegaon, Pune, Maharashtra, India`.  the value in the state was showing me something weirder like this `Dr D Y Patil Knowledge city, Charholi, Lohegaon, Pune, Maharashtra 412105, India`

Comment: Oh I see so you don't want the formatted_address. Then this is easier, use `document.getElementById("pac-input").value`. I'll edit my answer.